# Why i can not directly used a ObservableCollection in Bindings

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I would like to know why I can not directly used a ObservableCollection from my MainWindow.xaml .

Code:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public ObservableCollection<DummyData> tmpLst = new ObservableCollection<DummyData>();

    public ObservableCollection<DummyData> Dummy
    {
        get { return tmpLst; }
    }

    private void CreateDummy()
    {
        for (int x = 1; x < 10; x++)
        {
            tmpLst.Add(new DummyData() { text = ("DummyData =" + x), wert = x });
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {            
        InitializeComponent();
        CreateDummy();
    }
}
```

Xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication2"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <DataGrid Name="testGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
              DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
              ItemsSource="{Binding tmpLst}"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Xaml - Works:

```
<DataGrid Name="testGrid"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True" 
          DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"
          ItemsSource="{Binding Dummy}"/>
```

If I used the Dummy and not the tmpLst the Grid Shows me the data, maybe I miss  or forget something... ?

Comment: Because it has to be property not a field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Binding to work correctly, you have to use a Property and not a public Field.

There is a concept called Dependency Property in WPF.

Properties hold immense importance in WPF.

Few good links :

[DataBinding FAQ](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpfsdk/archive/2006/10/19/wpf-basic-data-binding-faq.aspx)

[Scott's DataBinding tutorial](http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/20/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-two.html)

Answer (score 0):

You missed out nothing.

The binding engine requires the binding target to be a property. Binding to a field will never work.